# How can I include the article number in the bibliography of Microsoft Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, citations

I have an issue with the referencing tool in Microsoft Word. To cite a journal article, I typically have to add Authors, Title, Journal Name, Year, Pages, Volume and Issue.

However, some journals refer to articles using an [article number](https://libguides.jcu.edu.au/harvard/journal-article#s-lg-box-19962733) instead of pages. Using Harvard format to cite them, the proper format should be something like this:

Marx, K., Kant, I, 2022. Ideas on rabbits farming. *Journal of dead philosophers writing about mundane things*, article no: e003131.

Is there a simple way to achieve that? If I put the code instead of Volume or Pages, the citation in the reference is shown with "Volume: e003131" or "Pages: e003131" at the end. If I add the code to the journal name, it is shown in italics.

How can I add this article number to the reference? Is there perhaps a way to use set a custom field?

Comment: I was likely not clear enough in the question: even changing to APA for example, that has a standard way of addressing article number as a field (for example, https://apastyle.apa.org/style-grammar-guidelines/references/examples/journal-article-references) there is the same issue. My issue is that there is no "article number", or similar field, in the Word Referencing system, irrespectively of the citation style. I could edit a style to visualize the "volume" or "DOI" in that way, but I do not think it is the "proper" solution.

Comment: I see, I've edited your question to clarify what I think you're asking and voted to re-open. Still, after a few tests in Word I am afraid that creating your own citation style is the way to go here, but perhaps someone else can come up with less labour intensive solution